# Class not found (ADT 22)

Tags: android, dalvik, eclipse-adt, samsung-mobile-sdk

I am studying Look API (from Samsung Mobile SDK). To do this I have put sample from Samsung Mobile SDK to my app. There is nothing complex, just Activity is created and a texview from one of Look classes is instintiated.

When I run the app on a simulator (open smartclip activity) I got error from dalvikvm. From LogCat:

`Could not find class 'com.samsung.android.sdk.look.smartclip.SlookSmartClip$1', referenced from method com.samsung.android.sdk.look.smartclip.SlookSmartClip.setDataExtractionListener`

I use ADT bundle with Mobile SDK 1.0.2 (Look is 1.0.0). 
Simulator device is Android 4.2.2 without Look support (but it does not matter as all files exported).
I verified that the project configured correctly to export the look.jar into resulting apk-file.
I have checked that all the external libraries are exproted to apk and have de-dexed the resulting classes.dex to verify that class SlookSmartClip$1 is actually there.

Maybe this question is more general to ADT 22 + 3rd party jar library problem. But almost always people do not export the files propertly, here I do not have this issue.

Do you know what is the problem?

PS: I tried to unchecked Android Private Library in export. After that the libraries are not appear in bin/dexedLibs and not in apk (classes.dex). After checking again (cleaning project all the time), they appear in bin/dedexedLibs and packaged into apk in classes.dex. I do not understand how dalvikvm cannot find them...

Comment: Hmm... seems like I manged to run the apk without ClassNotFound error after switching from JavaRE 1.6 to 1.7. Actually my settings was initially set to 1.7 and some time ago I just put it to 1.6 following one of suggestions. After that I tried to remove->clean->add->clean jars. Reinstall ADT... many other things... and now tried to return Java 1.6 back to original 1.7. Thus, I do not really know what helped in the middle.

Comment: Nope, I am wrong... the error did not disappear.

Answer (score 0):

This error is generated only when library is not well included you need to add the lib jar provided by samsung to the project

`right click project-> properties -> java build path -> libraries.`

and add your jar

Comment: It is already in libraries under more general section "Android Private Libraries".

Comment: shall it be under Android Private Libraries? dont they provide a sample project or something?

Comment: Hm... I do not know, but if it is there (in Android Private Library) then it means it already seen and treated the same way as you explicitly add the jar there. To start with, I simply imported their sample project into my eclipse project (so I already trying to compile and run the sample project).